# Type variable error

Tags: haskell, types

I am currently working on a game engine in Haskell and now I am trying to implement a messaging system between subsystems of this engine (I am using a Publisher-Subscriber pattern). You can check out the code as a whole at [here on my github profile](https://github.com/nek0/affection). I implemented a "Participant" typeclass for all datatypes participating in my Messaging system as follows:

```
class (Show m, Message m) => Participant prt m where
  -- | Function to get the lsit of subscribers from the participant
  partSubscribers
    :: prt
    -- ^ the participant
    -> forall us. Affection us [(m -> Affection us ())]
    -- ^ List of Subscriber functions

  -- | Subscribe to the 'Participant''s events
  partSubscribe
    :: prt
    -- ^ The 'Participant' to subscribe to
    -> (forall us. m -> Affection us ())
    -- ^ What to do in case of a 'Message'
    -- (Subscriber function)
    -> Affection us UUID
    -- ^ 'UUID' of the registered subscriber Function

  -- | Unsubscribe a Subscriber function from Participant
  partUnSubscribe
    :: prt             -- ^ The 'Participant' to unsubscribe from
    -> UUID            -- ^ The subscriber function's 'UUID'
    -> Affection us ()

  -- | Get the 'Participant' to emit a 'Message' on all of its subscribers
  partEmit
    :: prt             -- ^ The 'Participant'
    -> m               -- ^ The 'Message' to emit
    -> Affection us ()
  partEmit p m = do
    liftIO $ logIO Debug $ "Emitting message: " ++ show m
    l <- partSubscribers p
    mapM_ ($ m) l
```

A concrete implementation of this Typeclass looks like this. I'm making the use of the Package `stm`:

```
data AffectionWindow us = AffectionWindow
  { windowSubscribers
      :: forall us. TVar [(UUID, WindowMessage -> Affection us ())]
  }

instance Participant (AffectionWindow us) WindowMessage where
  partSubscribe p funct = do
    uuid <- genUUID
    liftIO $ atomically $ modifyTVar' (windowSubscribers p) ((uuid, funct) :)
    return uuid

  partUnSubscribe p uuid =
    liftIO $ atomically $ modifyTVar' (windowSubscribers p)
      (filter (\(u, _) -> u /= uuid))

  partSubscribers p = do
    subTups <- liftIO $ readTVarIO $ windowSubscribers p
    return $ map snd subTups
```

This code compiles fine as a library, but when I try to use this in a minimal example, it fails to compile. The code, where it fails looks like this:

```
load :: IO StateData
load = do
  empty1 <- newTVarIO []
  -- ([] :: [(UUID, WindowMessage -> Affection StateData ())])
  empty2 <- newTVarIO []
  -- ([] :: [(UUID, MouseMessage -> Affection StateData ())])
  empty3 <- newTVarIO []
  -- ([] :: [(UUID, KeyboardMessage -> Affection StateData ())])
  return $ StateData $ Subsystems
    (AffectionWindow empty1)
    (AffectionMouse empty2)
    (AffectionKeyboard empty3)
```

and the error message is:

```
examples/example00.hs:43:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a0’
                     with ‘(UUID, WindowMessage -> Affection us1 ())’
        because type variable ‘us1’ would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall us1. TVar [(UUID, WindowMessage -> Affection us1 ())]
        at examples/example00.hs:43:6-27
      Expected type: TVar [(UUID, WindowMessage -> Affection us1 ())]
        Actual type: TVar [a0]
    • In the first argument of ‘AffectionWindow’, namely ‘empty1’
      In the first argument of ‘Subsystems’, namely
        ‘(AffectionWindow empty1)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘Subsystems
           (AffectionWindow empty1)
           (AffectionMouse empty2)
           (AffectionKeyboard empty3)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        empty1 :: TVar [a0] (bound at examples/example00.hs:39:3)
   |
43 |     (AffectionWindow empty1)
   |                      ^^^^^^
```

I have never encountered any error like this and I'm at my wits end.
Hopefully somebody in here knows the solution.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you need _a polymorphic `TVar`_? That seems a really daring approach... you certainly can't create one just with `newTVarIO`. What is the purpose of all this universally-quantified `Affection` anyway? If the `us` argument is completely phantom, this _might_ be a use case for `unsafeCoerce`, but make sure you know very well why you want that foo at all.

Comment: if you mean the `us` type parameter, then yes, I need it. This is the games' state, which is supplied by the implementor of the game.
`Affection` is the state transformer monad holding the state.

Comment: But surely it will be sufficient to parameterise the `AffectionWindow` to a single value, at compile-time? Why don't you just use that parameter, but quantify a new one in the `windowSubscriber` field?

Comment: I just learned that I can omit the `us` paramater totally from the `AffectionWindow`, but the paramater stays in the subscriber function. I tried it out, but it still fails to compile. How do I tell the Compiler, that the type variable `us` equals `StateData` in the example application?

Comment: You _can't_ tell the compiler that `us` equals anything particular, because the field `windowSubscribers :: ∀ us. TVar [(UUID, WindowMessage -> Affection us ())]` must by signature always contain a fully polymorphic value. Which is, I reckon, not really what you want though.

Comment: You are right, This is not what I want.

Comment: Well, why did you put in the universal quantifier then?

Comment: Because the compiler told me it needs it. I see that I made an error wit the whole `data AffectionWindow` business. I can't implement the type on the engine side, this is something the game implementation must do.